# Android SQL statement

Tags: sql, where-clause

I'm new to SQL and I believe there is maybe a mistake.
I would search my database with

```
SELECT * FROM Data WHERE xx='4*'
```

I need all data where in colum xx is the first number 4 (string)
44545 and 493435 and 4111111 and so on with all other columns

Is that Statement ok?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must use the `LIKE` syntax instead of the equality operator `=`:

```
SELECT * FROM Data WHERE xx LIKE '4%'
```

Comment: Hey :)) you are my hero of the day, that's it - it works Thank you

Comment: Glad to be of help. Please show your appreciation by marking my post as an accepted answer.